# How get a value from NSDictionary and move it to an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsarray

I'm sure this question has been asked dozens of times on here, but I can't seem to find anything even close to what I need. I'm having a little bit of a problem getting this right. I need to get a value out of an `NSDictionary` and place it into an `NSArray`.

```
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"ID1":@{
                                   @"mainPhone": @"<number>",
                                   @"Address": @"<address>",
                                   @"City": @"<Tulsa, OK>",
                                   @"Date": @"1-1-2017",
                                   @"Person1": @{
                                               @"First": @"<FirstName>",
                                               @"Last":  @"<LastName>",
                                               @"Phone": @"<number>",
                                               @"Email": @"email@gmail.com",
                                               @"Birth": @"<date>",
                                               @"ID":    @"12345",
                                   },
                                   @"Person2": @{
                                               @"First": @"<FirstName>",
                                               @"Last":  @"<LastName>",
                                               @"Phone": @"<number>",
                                               @"Email": @"email@gmail.com",
                                               @"Birth": @"<date>",
                                               @"ID":    @"12345",
                              },
                              @"ID2":@{
                                   @"mainPhone": @"<number>",
                                   @"Address": @"<address>",
                                   @"City": @"<Tulsa, OK>",
                                   @"Date": @"1-1-2017",
                                   @"Person3": @{
                                               @"First": @"<FirstName>",
                                               @"Last":  @"<LastName>",
                                               @"Phone": @"<number>",
                                               @"Email": @"email@gmail.com",
                                               @"Birth": @"<date>",
                                               @"ID":    @"12345",
                                   },
                                   @"Person4": @{
                                               @"First": @"<FirstName>",
                                               @"Last":  @"<LastName>",
                                               @"Phone": @"<number>",
                                               @"Email": @"email@gmail.com",
                                               @"Birth": @"<date>",
                                               @"ID":    @"12345",
                              },
              };
```

In my example dictionary above, I need to get the key `First` under the 3rd layer dictionary and load it into an array. The dictionaries marked `ID` and `Person` will be assigned separate ID numbers will be the only keys that will not be static. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `objectForKey`?`[dictionary objectForKey:@"ID"] objectForKey:@"Person"] objectForKey:@"First"]]]`

Comment: you also can do it `[dict valueForKeyPath:@"key1.@specialKey.key3"]`

Comment: first check your open & close curly brace brackets. is it correct?

Comment: @Mukesh, I believe it is, what I have up there is only a small example of what I'm really working with.

Comment: Is it really that easy? I understand how to get the values for the keys, but I thought there was more to getting them into an NSArray.

Comment: @trainkid93 Are you able to get `First` value now?

Comment: @NiravD, Yes, but only under the first instance of 'Person'. The dictionary marked 'Person' in my example is only a single example of what will be as many as 8 similar instances. The dictionary titled 'ID' will have an indefinite amount of instances.

Comment: @trainkid93 You mean to say id1 contains person1 , person2... then id2 contains person3,person4.. like that? It is batter if you show us real json with key

Comment: I don't have any JSON yet. I'm not as experienced with JSON yet, but I can figure it out if I have an Obj-C equivalent. Let me post a larger version of my example to make things more clear.

Comment: @trainkid93 Yes that will give us more idea.

Comment: Your Person key is not static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can go loop through the dictionary and first idKey then access that dictionary and access its detail by loop through it.

```
for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    NSDictionary *idDic = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    for (NSString *idDicKey in idDic) {
        if ([[idDic objectForKey:idDicKey] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSString *firstName = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.First",key, idDicKey]];
            NSLog(@"%@",firstName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use if/else condition to get other keys value like mainPhone, Address,City etc..